# Facebook open Graph Timeline for koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline, koala

How to use Koala to implement features on Timeline facebook? Its that still remain the same with the current version of the koala, or it have to add some parameter on the existing function or have new way to implement with koala??

any have tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

See the Koala docs: https://github.com/arsduo/koala

```
@graph.put_connections("me", "namespace:action", :object => object_url)
```